# Popup won't popup in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, popup

I'm trying to get a popup to appear from a link in an MVC page, but the popup isn't popping up. The partial view is just replacing the current page in the browser. Why isn't is just leaving my current page in place and giving me a popup? My partial view just has a few words of text in it.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "Open popup",
    "GetNotes",
    new { id = "5" },
    new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "GET", 
            UpdateTargetId = "result", 
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
            OnSuccess = "openPopup"
        })

<br />

<div id="result" style="display:none;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#result").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Title',
        width: 500,
        height: 'auto',
        modal: true
    });

    function openPopup() {
        $("#result").dialog("open");
    }

</script>
```

**UPDATE:**

Here's the complete source (from "View Source") I'm currently trying. When I click the link, nothing happens. What's going on? Am I missing a js file or something?

By the way, this URL is returning my partial view (currently just a couple words of plain text):

```
http://localhost:40353/Quote/GetNotes/5
```

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/people.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/kendo.web.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/console.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

        <link href="/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/Styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/Styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.20/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    </head>

    <body>
<div id="result" style="display:none;"></div>

<a href="#" id="OpenPopup"> open popup </a>

        <script type="text/javascript">
                $("#result").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    title: 'Title',
                    width: 500,
                    height: 'auto',
                    modal: true
                });

                $("#OpenPopup").click(function () {
                    $("#result").dialog("open");
                    $("#result").load("Quote/GetNotes/5");
                });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing reference to "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" script file in the `<head>` section of your Layout (Master) Page.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Good call, Kapil. Now I'm making some headway. After removing style="display:none;" from the div and adding the reference you showed me, the GET is happening and the div is showing it, but it just shows the partial view below the link, not as a popup.

Comment: Check your controller, is action method GetNotes() return partial view ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the partial view replaces your view in the browsers is @Ajax.ActionLink renders as a formed  tag in the browser. So when your click on the link your actually.

What I presume you want to do is open the popup and place the partial's contents into the popup?

There is a few ways to achieve this.

Change your actionlink to a normal  open popup

```
<a href="#" id="OpenPopup"> open popup </a>
```

And add this function

```
    $("#OpenPopup").click(function() {
      $("#result").dialog("open");
      // This is a neat wrapper that does a get request to the url specified and loads the html into the target div
      $("#result").load("/GetNotes/5");
    });
```

Comment: Tried this, but nothing at all happens when I click on the link. jquery-1.5.1.min.js is included in the calling page.

Answer (score 0):

Check as well in your _Layout at the bottom:

```
</div>
  </div>
    </footer>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

Remove

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

and the modal pop up will run.